# Transition matrix and linearly dependent equations

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let P be a Markov chain transition matrix. Namely, the sum of each of its rows equals to 1. Then why is it that the set of equations given by $\pi=\pi P$ would always have one linearly dependent equation? what is the algebraic reason for it?

Comment: What do you know about eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: I know what are eigenvalues, and I know that P would always have an eigenvalue which is equal to 1. That's the reason? how so?

Answer (score 0):

Summing the RHS of the equations given by $\pi =\pi P$ yields $\sum_{i=1}^n \pi_i=1$. Since $\sum_{j=1}^n P_{ij}=1$ for $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$, summing the LHS of those equations yields
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n P_{ij}\pi_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \pi_i = 1.
$$
So if we add the first $n-1$ equation to the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ equation, we get the equation $1=1$, which is redundant. Therefore the system of equations is linearly dependent.